# Excel Cell is blank but not empty

Tags: excel, if-statement

All of my cells have formulas linking to other cells and sheets within a spreadsheet I have created, therefore none of my cells are 'empty'.

I have researched extensively but I cannot work out a formula to have cells be blank when other cells are blank (but not empty as they have a formula).  Any advice, I have tried the following:

```
IF((C15<0)," ",($B15*$C15))
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("%",C15))," ",($B15*$C15))
IF(ISBLANK(C15)," ", ($B15*$C15))
```

[screenshot of my spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcaPW.png)

Comment: Are your formulas putting a string containing a space or an empty string with nothing inside?

Comment: I do not understand the question - the formula should bring back a number unless I've asked it not to due to another cell being blank (although its coming back with 'VALUE because the cell is not empty)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119614/return-empty-cell-from-formula-in-excel and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881053/how-to-make-an-excel-cell-equal-to-empty-possibly-via-vba-code Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768020/if-statement-how-to-leave-cell-blank-if-condition-is-false-does-not-work

Comment: And this:  https://superuser.com/questions/837038/excel-how-to-create-truly-blank-cells-from-formula-so-that-they-wont-show-up   The number format answer might do what you want.

Comment: thank you, I will check it out