# select rows that are not empty within range

Tags: excel, vba

I had some columns that contains data. I'm planning to `select` them then send using workbook envelope. The problem is that some cells are empty and I do not want to select them.

**How can I avoid rows with blank values for Column E?**

This is what I tried so far.

```
' This will select all
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("holo").Range("A10:D100,E10:E100").Select

' Tried using If 
Dim rg As Range
For Each rg In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("holo").Range("A10:D100,E10:E100").Select
If rg <> "" Then
rg.Select
Debug.Print rg.Address + "is not empty"
End If
Next
```

Comment: The quickest method depends on whether the cells in column E contain values resolved from formulas or typed values. Also it is important to know whether there are any zero length strings (e.g. `""`) which are not considered truly blank.

Comment: @Jeeped I just double checked the column using `ctrl + ~` and thanks for the info about [True Blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881053/how-to-make-an-excel-cell-equal-to-empty-possibly-via-vba-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values in column E are typed vales and not resolved from a formula then try,

```
dim rg as range
with worksheets("holo").usedrange
   on error resume next
   set rg = .columns("E").specialcells(xlCellTypeConstants, 7)
   on error goto 0
   if not rg is nothing then
       'do something with rg
   end if
end with
```

Comment: Sorry so how can I implement it? like how to use the `rg` to select **rows** that are not blank.

Comment: 1. try `rg.entirerow.select` to see if it is collecting the correct union of cells. 2. I'm sorry but I have no idea how to program a 'windows envelope'.

Comment: I never used the `specialcells` before so I did a check. From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel), the value for `xlCellTypeConstants` shouldnt be 2? What does that 7 do?

Comment: 2 is xlTextValues; 7 is xlTextValues + xlNumbers + xlLogical. I figured you didn't want errors.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the code looks good. **These values can be added together to return more than one type.** I miss that :( .

Comment: Sorry, I totally forget about Other Columns. The selection is depends on Column E and then select the row data that are not empty. Can I set the columns as well? I do not wish to get columns with irrelevant data.

Comment: if you require data from columns A-Z where E is not blank then `set rg = intersect(.range("a:z"), .columns("E").specialcells(xlCellTypeConstants, 7).entirerow)`